# Two-dimensional difference test

Tags: differences

Suppose I need to find out whether both the average height and the average weight of a person in two populations are the same. Is there a standard extension of the difference test in two dimensions? If not, what are the common techniques for solving this problem?

Comment: You probably want [Hotelling's $T^2$ Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution).